# Setting up S3QL with FIWARE Object Storage GE (Openstack Swift)

Tags: fiware, openstack-swift, s3ql

I am trying to setup S3QL with Object Storage GE and there seems to be only one piece of information missing.

I successfully installed S3QL thanks to this pretty good tutorial: https://dmsimard.com/2014/09/29/s3ql-a-filesystem-over-http-with-swift/

Now I am stuck when trying to mount an object-container 'test' that I created in region 'Lannion2'.

The URL-syntax requires a 'region' to be defined (`swiftks://<hostname>[:<port>]/<region>:<container>`) but I have no clue how this maps to the fiware-stack. When trying the following command, s3ql seems to succeed in connecting and authenticating with Keystone but cannot find the region.

```
mkfs.s3ql swiftks://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/Lannion2:test --backend-options no-ssl
Enter backend login:
Enter backend passphrase:
```

Results in:

```
No accessible object storage service found in region Lannion2 (available regions: )
```

Unfortunately no available regions are listed in the response. Authentication works correctly as mistyping login or passphrase results in an authentication-error.

Is there any documentation about the naming of regions in keystone/fiware cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate to keystone via: 
 Post http://cloud.lab.fi-ware.org:4730/v2.0/tokens with Content-type application/json and Body: {"auth": {"passwordCredentials": 
{"username": "***", "password": "***"}, "tenantId":"***"}}

In the response, you should receive a list of endpoints, including a swift endpoint. There should be an entry there that looks like:
{"adminURL": "***", "region": "Lannion2", "internalURL": "***:8080/v1/AUTH_***", "id": "***", "publicURL": "***/v1/AUTH_***"}